# Convert file tree format

Tags: javascript, directory, format

I have the following file tree

```js
{
  "/": {
    "apps": {
      "text-open": {
        "app.js": null
      },
      "html-open": {
        "app.js": null
      },
      "editor": {
        "app.js": null,
        "index.html": null
      }
    },
    "Images": {
      "image.png": null
    },
    "Documents": {
      "README.txt": null,
      "example.txt": null
    }
  }
}
```

And I have a treeview component that can display it visually but it takes a different format. It requires this:

```js
{
  label: "/", children: [
    {label: "apps", path: "/apps", children: [
      {label: "text-open", path: "/apps/text-open", children: [
        {label: "app.js", path: "/apps/text-open/app.js"},
      ]},
      {label: "html-open", path: "/apps/html-open", children: [
        {label: "app.js", path: "/apps/html-open/app.js"},
      ]},
       {label: "editor", path: "/apps/editor", children: [
        {label: "app.js", path: "/apps/editor/app.js"},
        {label: "index.html", path: "/apps/editor/index.html"},
      ]},
    ]},
    {label: "Documents", path: "/Documents", children: [
      {label: "README.txt", path: "/Documents/README.txt"},
      {label: "example.txt", path: "/Documents/example.txt"},
    ]},
    {label: "Images", path: "/Images", children: [
      {label: "image.png", path: "/Images/image.png"},
    ]},
  ],
}
```

I have not been able to think of a way to convert between these two formats (I need vanilla JS).
Any help converting would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ask ChatGPT, it should be able to come up with the code

Comment: @Dimava surely you're joking.

Comment: I have been prompting Bing AI now for 15 minutes to no avail....

Comment: https://tsplay.dev/WzD14N

Comment: I'm impressed, BingAI actually did it, it only took me 36 minutes

Comment: @Pointy apparently I did not lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion can be completed by this function:

```js
function convertFileTreeToTreeView(fileTree) {
  const root = {label: "/", children: []};
  const stack = [[root, fileTree]];
  while (stack.length > 0) {
    const [parent, node] = stack.pop();
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(node)) {
      const path = parent.path ? `${parent.path}/${key}` : `/${key}`;
      if (value === null) {
        parent.children.push({label: key, path});
      } else {
        const child = {label: key, path, children: []};
        parent.children.push(child);
        stack.push([child, value]);
      }
    }
  }
  return root;
}
```